# Prove or disprove that Y = AX-C

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix such that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = n \le m$.  Prove, or disprove using a counter example:

Every $m\times n$ matrix $Y$ has a decomposition $Y = AX-C$, where $X$ and $A^TC$ are nonnegative semidefinite symmetric matrices.

I have a feeling this is false, but I can't come up with a good counter example to show this.
I've been trying to find a $Y$ such that $X$ would have to be non semidefinite to construct this $Y$.

Is it possible that the statement is true?

This is a problem from a book on semidefinite optimization.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant: I don't see anything wrong with fixing a matrix and asking if every matrix has a decomposition in terms of the first one and and some others. Is that what was intended, user?

Comment: My suspicion is that something is missing from the statement. Care to point us to the reference you're talking about? I do semidefinite programming as part of my work, I might be familiar with the text.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition is false as stated.

Let $A$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then the decomposition reduces to $X-C$, where both $X$ and $C$ are symmetric. Clearly no asymmetric $Y$ has such a decomposition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I can't believe I didn't see this before

Comment: That's why I think there's something missing from the statement. I don't think a counterexample this basic would be likely to be missed by the authors. Can you please share the reference?